# Is that IGBT will failure if apply Vce with out gate pulse, and driver supply

Tags: power-electronics

I gave 100v dc in the Igbt with out gate supply, The IGBT gate section went failure. Please tell me whether the method  I tested will create problem.

Comment: What is the specification of the IGBT, link to a data sheet would be the best thing to do. What does 'with out gate supply' mean? Open circuit, 0v, other? How do you know the gate section has failed, rather than some other part? Tell us what measurements you have made, and what it does do, guessing at what's wrong doesn't help.

Comment: Actually the rating of my IPM module is 1200V. There is a separate  connector for driver and PWM logic. I planed to give DC supply first and then to give gate driver voltage and pwm. so I didnt switched on the driver supply and pwm. i applied the 100V dc. suddenly the DC voltage drops to 16V. I removed the IPM and then I checked the DC sourec its fine. Than I tested the ipms gate connection. It shows sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you left the gate open and applied 100VDC of the correct polarity the IGBT can and will fail even though nobody makes IGBTs with drain source ratings so low .                           This can be because the high impedence           gate can have a static charge on it .If the static voltage isnt enough to destroy the gate oxide layer its often enough to turn the device half on .This could result in extremely high power dissipation destroying the device .IGBTs arnt happy in analog mode and generally are not specified for linear operation.Place a 1K resister between gate and source to avoid blowing up the next device .Nondestructive testing .

Comment: thank you Reply Autistic.. I have connected the driver circuit, but didn't gave supply for the drivers.